# ListView in a Relative Layout

Tags: android

Howdy,
I would like to implement a ListView in a Relative Layout - however, that ListView should not be scrollable. Meaning: It should show all of it's elements in the RelativeLayout/LinearLayout.

The elements should change the colors on touch and call an intent on click.

What would be the best approach to reach that goal? CustomListView implementation, maybe I don't even need to use a listview?

Comment: Why are you implementing that in a listview? It sounds like you really want a linearlayout.

Comment: I'm getting data out of my application which I want to show to the user - I have a descriptive item like 'counter 1' which has several meals assigned to it. I want to show those in 2 textviews next to each other and make both click/touchable. The easiest way which I read was to use a listview :).

I mainly chose that way because my approach on creating new tablerows with textviews ended not satisfactory - I was not able to set styles without the attributeset.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best approach to reach that goal?

Have a very short list. `ListView` only scrolls if you have more items than fits on the screen.